# z-index not stacking properly

Tags: css, z-index

I have this page [HERE](http://www.lilbuilders.com/index2.htm). And the [CSS is HERE](http://www.lilbuilders.com/css/main.css). I would like `<div id="main-img">` to be behind `<header>`. I have done z-index so many times before but I just cannot figure out what I'm missing here. 
Thanks!!

Comment: Please post your code HERE.

Comment: Note that the higher a z-index is, the closer to the front the element becomes (if it has a positioning). You seem to have reversed that concept in setting your z-indices for `#main-img` and `<header>`. (As the former is currently set to 9999, and the latter to 1.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your div header has position relative, z-index only works with same position type
Try to change your style of your header like this:

```
header {
        top:0;
        left:0;
        position: absolute;
        height: 172px;
        max-width: 980px;
        z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: "z.index only works with position absolute" not true.

Comment: I can't believe it, I had the two mixed up. Wow thanks and sorry for stupid question!

Comment: Thanks glad to help you accept the answer to help other people with same problem @Kim